# CakePHP : Custom Query in Controller: How to check if it was successful?

Tags: cakephp

I'm doing a manual update to my database with a custom query, like so:

```
$this->Model->query("UPDATE table SET attribute='1' WHERE condition='".
$variable);
```

It's all good, it works fine. But how can I check if the result, in
this case the update, was successful?

I need to check if it was successful, so I can redirect after it, and
post a message to the user.

Does query return true or false after it has been executed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query), `query` returns:

> array or **boolean indicating success / failure** depending on the query executed

This would have taken about 4 seconds to test with your own code or to look up in the docs.